# R CRAN check works great on local Mac OS, but failed on Windows (win-builder web). Why?

Tags: r, windows, macos, cran

I have my R package checked on local Mac OS via `R CMD check --as-cran`. Everything works great: no errors, no warnings, just 1 note about first submission, all test files passed! However, when I submit my `.tar.gz` package file to the http://win-builder.r-project.org to check on Windows. Some errors occurred when running the examples.

The main issue is related to the object created by `Matrix`. All errors indicated `invalid class "dgCMatrix" object: Dimnames[1] is not a character vector`. Detailed check log is attached below.

I checked the examples on local machine line-by-line, but cannot identify the problem.

Is the error caused by that maybe the `Matrix` package was written differently for Mac OS and Windows platforms?

```
* checking examples ...
** running examples for arch 'i386' ... ERROR
Running examples in 'grpregOverlap-Ex.R' failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: cv.grpregOverlap
> ### Title: Cross-validation for choosing regularization parameter lambda
> ### Aliases: cv.grpregOverlap
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> ## linear regression, a simulation demo.
> set.seed(123)
> group <- list(gr1 = c(1, 2, 3),
+               gr2 = c(1, 4),
+               gr3 = c(2, 4, 5),
+               gr4 = c(3, 5),
+               gr5 = c(6))
> beta.latent.T <- c(5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0) # true latent coefficients.
> # beta.T <- c(5, 5, 10, 0, 5, 0), true variables: 1, 2, 3, 5; true groups: 1, 4.
> X <- matrix(rnorm(n = 6*100), ncol = 6)
> X.latent <- expandX(X, group)
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class "dgCMatrix" object: Dimnames[1] is not a character vector
Calls: expandX ... initialize -> callNextMethod -> .nextMethod -> validObject
Execution halted
```

I also attached source code for the two related functions.

```
expandX <- function(X, group) {
  incidence.mat <- incidenceMatrix(X, group) # group membership incidence matrix
  over.mat <- Matrix(incidence.mat %*% t(incidence.mat), sparse = TRUE, 
                     dimnames = dimnames(incidence.mat)) # overlap matrix
  grp.vec <- rep(1:nrow(over.mat), times = diag(over.mat)) # group index vector

  # expand X to X.latent
  X.latent <- NULL
  names <- NULL

  ## the following code will automatically remove variables not included in 'group'
  for(i in 1:nrow(incidence.mat)) {
    idx <- incidence.mat[i,]==1
    X.latent <- cbind(X.latent, X[, idx, drop=FALSE])
    names <- c(names, colnames(incidence.mat)[idx])
  }
  colnames(X.latent) <- paste('grp', grp.vec, '_', names, sep = "")
  X.latent
}

incidenceMatrix <- function(X, group) {
  n <- nrow(X)
  p <- ncol(X)
  if (class(group) != 'list') {
    stop("Argument 'group' must be a list of integer indices or character names of variables!")
  }
  J <- length(group)
  grp.mat <- Matrix(0, nrow = J, ncol = p, dimnames=list(rep(NA, J),
                                                         rep(NA, p)))    
  if(is.null(colnames(X))) {
    colnames(X) <- paste("V", 1:ncol(X), sep="")    
  }
  if (is.null(names(group))) {
    names(group) <- paste("grp", 1:J, sep="")
  }

  if (class(group[[1]]) == 'numeric') {
    for (i in 1:J) {
      ind <- group[[i]]
      grp.mat[i, ind] <- 1
      colnames(grp.mat)[ind] <- colnames(X)[ind]
    }
  } else { ## character, names of variables
    for (i in 1:J) {
      grp.i <- as.character(group[[i]])
      ind <- colnames(X) %in% grp.i
      grp.mat[i, ] <- 1*ind
      colnames(grp.mat)[ind] <- colnames(X)[ind]
    }
  }
  rownames(grp.mat) <- as.character(names(group))
  # check grp.mat
  if (all(grp.mat == 0)) {
    stop("The names of variables in X don't match with names in group!")
  }

  grp.mat
}
```

**Update:**

Here is the link to the R package on GitHub.  https://github.com/YaohuiZeng/grpregOverlap. Hope this provide the whole picture, though the functions related to the issue are supposedly the two functions I posted. I really appreciate if you could help figure out the issue. Otherwise, I think I might just try to change the package by not use `Matrix` to see whether that works.

Comment: a link to your pkg source wld be more helpful

Comment: @hrbrmstr, Thanks for the comment. I've updated my question and added the link.

Comment: thx. Well, the "good" news is that I can reproduce it _on_ OS X (R 3.2.2, El Capitan). What version of `Matrix` do you have? Mine is `1.2-2`.

Comment: that's strange. My ``Matrix`` package is 1.2-0.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, if I understand correctly, we don't need to pre-install ``Matrix`` package. It is loaded automatically as it's listed in ``Depends: R (>= 3.1.0), Matrix, grpreg``. So how could it be possible that ``Matrix`` loaded on my machine is 1.2-0, but on yours is 1.2-2?

Comment: I keep _very_ current with pkg updates since I build alot of pkgs. You should try it with 1.2-2

Comment: @hrbrmstr. Thanks for observing this. I will try it. but again my confusion is, since R would automatically load the dependencies, including ``Matrix``. How could I request loading the most updated version of ``Matrix`` package?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thanks for helping identify the bugs. It has been fixed.

Comment: Congrats! I saw the pkg on CRAN. Well done!

Comment: @hrbrmstr, yes, it's on CRAN now. Thanks again for your help!